# What was the well-known Russian song Lean wanted for Doctor Zhivago?

Tags: soundtrack, doctor-zhivago

What was the well-known Russian song the director David Lean wanted for his movie *Doctor Zhivago*? See quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lara%27s_Theme):

> Initially Lean had desired to use a well-known Russian song but could not locate the rights to it, and delegated responsibility to Jarre.

Maurice Jarre came up with *Lara's Theme* in place but was it influenced by it?

Comment: In other languages wikipedia states that Lean wanted traditional russian music and folk songs arranged by Jarre for contemoporary times. And they cite source as Constantine Santas: The Epic Films of David Lean

Comment: okay so in other languages it is sourced I'll try to get Constantine Santas: The Epic Films of David Lean from the library if nobody comes up with an anser to see if it mentions what Russian music / folk songs that was.